# How to Capture Youtube Video Start Using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

**Programming Language:** Javascript and Youtube Javascript API
**Problem:**
A website has multiple youtube videos placed on it using Javascript API. Call/Report to another function as soon as a user starts watching videos.
**Code I have so far:**

```
var youTubePlayerLoggers = {};
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    var video = document.getElementById(playerId);
    youTubePlayerLoggers[playerId] = function (newState) {            
            if (newState == 1) {
              if (video && video.getDuration) {
                if (video.getCurrentTime() == 0) {                  
                  UserStartedVideo('param1', 'param2');
                }          
               }
            }
          };
     video.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'youTubePlayerLoggers.' + playerId);
     video.addEventListener('onError', 'onPlayerError');
        }

function UserStartedVideo(param1,param2){
}
```

In the 5th line of the code I am checking if newState == 1 (i.e user has clicked on play button) then if the video.getCurrentTime ==0 --> It is the start of the video by user.

**Issue I am having:**
I have multiple videos on the website. When I click on the play button of the first video, UserStartedVideo method is triggered. Similarly, UserStartedVideo method should be triggered as soon as I click on play button of the second video, but it is not happening.

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong or any otherway to capture start of the videos?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_status ?

how about setTimeout checking of player.getPlayerState() ?

Comment: player.getPlayerState() gives the status of the video i.e Unstarted, Playing, Paused,or Ended. I need to check whether the user has started the video or not. If I have a single video my code above works perfectly but I have multiple videos on the same page.